# Gamma Regressor - Some value(s) of y are out of the valid range of the loss 'HalfGammaLoss'

Tags: regression, machine-learning, generalized-linear-model, predictive-models, gamma-distribution

I am trying to use `GammaRegressor` to predict the customer revenue in the next 3 months, 6 months etc.

So, I tried using the GammaRegressor based on suggestions from the posts [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/596347/regression-for-only-positive-values-prediction).

My Y variable ranges from 0 to 6172000.9368

However, when I passed in my data, I got the below error

> GammaRegressor model failed to execute Some value(s) of y are out of
> the valid range of the loss 'HalfGammaLoss'.

When I researched online, I came across this github link [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/linear_model/_glm/glm.py) which has code snippet in line 227, 228 about value error.

So, not sure what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zero is not a valid value for a gamma distribution. The PDF has the gamma function in the denominator of a fraction. However:

$$
\underset{x\rightarrow 0^+}{\lim}\Gamma(x)=\infty
$$

This error message is alerting you to the fact that you have a value that cannot occur according to the assumed distribution.

Comment: So, we should make only predictions for customers who have revenue above 0? but in real time, there might be customers who have 0 revenue in certain look back period but we wish to predict for them (even if it is going to zero). Does adding values like `0.1` to `0` is okay?

Comment: Because I don't wish to avoid this customers. So then only option is tweedie? which goes from P=1 to P=2 inverse gamma etc?

Comment: @TheGreat [You can use square loss with a $\log$ link.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/591118/247274) There might be better loss functions and link functions for your work, but square loss with a $\log$ link could be fine, too.

Comment: Thanks, I referred your other post. So, I thought loss function is like a hyperparamter thay we can change but looks like scikit-learm doesn't have that here. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.GammaRegressor.html

Comment: Earlier, I used an AutoML solution which I giess had halfgamma loss as input. So, not sure how do we modify it?

Comment: @TheGreat What do you want to modify?

Comment: How do we change fron half gamma loss to square loss?